# Prove the Mobius transformation is the group of all biholomorphic preserving the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

The wikipedia entry [Mobius transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Subgroups_of_the_M%C3%B6bius_group) states the following.

The subgroup of all Möbius transformations that map the open disk $D:= \{z :|z| < 1\}$ to itself consists of all transformations of the form
$$f(z) = e^{i\phi} \frac{z + b}{\bar bz + 1}$$
with $\phi\in R$, and $|b| < 1$, $\bar b$ being the complex conjugate of $b$. This is equal to the group of all biholomorphic (or equivalently: bijective, angle-preserving and orientation-preserving) maps $D\to D$.

How does one prove that?

Comment: This is proved in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Cool. Would you mind providing the section or theorem number?

Comment: In my edition of the book it is Theorem 12.6. It comes under Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, @KaviRamaMurthy.